# Does Fragment gets destroyed if we destroy an activity containing it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

From what my understanding is regarding **Activities** and **Fragments** in Android, fragment is a sub-part of the activity in which it is called.

**So what I want to know is that if we finish or kill the Activity in which the fragment exists, how will it effect the fragment?**

Will the fragment also get destroyed?? or is it that the state of fragment is independent of the activity containing it? Please provide a proper clarification on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what my understanding is regarding Activities and Fragments in Android, fragment is a sub-part of the activity in which it is called.

**Yes you are right, fragments are sub parts added dynamically on run time**

So what I want to know is that if we finish or kill the Activity in which the fragment exists, how will it effect the fragment?

**If you kill/finish an Activity fragments will also be destroyed**

NOTE: Fragment lifecycle is dependent on Activity life cycle, if an Activity is dead so the fragments are.

Building fragment on an Activity is like building 2,3 or 4 story building. If base is destroyed then other stories are not supposed to be stable. Just keep this rule in mind. This will help you with understanding. And further more you can apply logging on Activity and Fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

**How the Activity state affects the Fragment**

Because a *Fragment* is always hosted by an *Activity*, the *Fragment* lifecycle is directly affected by the host *Activity* lifecycle. For example, when the *Activity* is paused, so are all *Fragments* in it, and when the *Activity* is destroyed, so are all *Fragments*.

Each lifecycle callback for the *Activity* results in a similar callback for each *Fragment*, as shown in the following table. For example, when the *Activity* receives [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()), it triggers a Fragment [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) for each *Fragment* in the *Activity*.

[image]

link: https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-1-fragments/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications.html

Also from official guide: "For instance, for an Activity, this (DESTROYED)state is reached right before Activity's onDestroy call"
link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#DESTROYED

Answer (score 0):

> As Fragment is embedded inside an Activity, it will be killed when
> Activity is killed. As contents of activity are first killed, fragment will
> be destroyed just before activity gets destroyed.